# NVM Throwing Errors on Mac

Tags: node.js, nvm

I've been using NVM for almost a year without any issues. I really like using it over regular Node. I created a new repo, and now I'm getting errors that don't make any sense. Now, I'm unable to use NPM commands.

CLI: `npm -v`

```
node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:126
    cachedCwd = rawMethods.cwd();
                           ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_cwd
    at process.wrappedCwd [as cwd] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:126:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/****/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/depd/index.js:25:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/****/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/agent.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14) {
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'uv_cwd'
}
```

Our projects use the .nvmrc file to reflect the Node version. When I run nvm use the following shows up. Normally, it also shows the NPM version, but now it doesn't.

```
Found 'project-path/.nvmrc' with version <v16.14.0>
Now using node v16.14.0 (npm v)
```

Running the npm install command also throws an error.

```
node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:126
    cachedCwd = rawMethods.cwd();
                           ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_cwd
    at process.wrappedCwd [as cwd] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:126:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/****/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/depd/index.js:25:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/****/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/agent.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14) {
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'uv_cwd'
}
```

I've also tried to upgrade to the latest verion (0.39.2), which failed.
Command: `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash`

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15916  100 15916    0     0  43223      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 44334
=> nvm is already installed in /Users/****/.nvm, trying to update using git
=> fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted
Failed to update nvm with v0.39.2, run 'git fetch' in /Users/****/.nvm yourself.
```

Running the `git fetch` command in the folder mentioned above, worked without errors.
All of the above errors are still being received.
Now, when I run `nvm -v`, it returns: `0.38.0`

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. I was running these commands from inside a project folder. I closed the terminal, and opened up a new one. Then the NVM upgrade command worked, and all other commands work correctly now.

Comment: This actually helped solve my issue. Guess I'll add it to my list of weird things to try when debugging console errors.